# FATCA XML - How to add multiple data in FATCA XML file

Tags: xml, tax

If anyone have knowledge about FATCA Xml schema than this is easy for them

I have format for single row of data

> 1) < FATCA_OECD > view alll data < /FATCA_OECD>

But When I have multiple rows of data

> < FATCA_OECD>  view alll data < /FATCA_OECD>
>
> < FATCA_OECD> view alll data < /FATCA_OECD>

But we all know that in XML File only one root node allow, so FATCA XML File which parent node I have to take for make it valid file?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple rows of data? `FATCA_OECD` is the root node, and you will only need one of it. If you have multiple accounts to report, you use multiple `AccountReport` entries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're only supposed to have a single FATCA_OECD node (this is the parent node I believe). Your rows of data should be in the reporting group section